# Saving Bert Fine tuned models

Tags: python, bert-language-model, transformer-model

After tuning my BERT model I want to save it to use it later (once the task is learned). I use these 2 lines to do it.

```
model_to_save.save_pretrained(output_dir)
tokenizer.save_pretrained(output_dir)
```

The problem is that it creates a +400Mb file that I cant upload to github because it is too big.

Is there a way to save the model creating a smaller file and loading it back later?

Regards

Comment: There are ways to deal with large files in version control, e.g., https://docs.github.com/en/github/managing-large-files/working-with-large-files/distributing-large-binaries

Comment: Solved thanks a lot :-)